# How do I give everyone except for me a potion effect?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need help making it so everyone in the server gets an effect except for me when I drop my specific item. I am using the execute command.

Comment: What did you come up with this far?

Answer (score 1):

on top of what Nik said, i believe you can also use the `name` selector to it, making it something like;

```
execute as @a[name=!<your_ign>] if entity <entity_to_check> run effect give @s <effect> <duration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tag yourself with the scoreboard tag "me" `/tag @s add me`, and then execute as all players without the 'me' tag `execute as @a[tag=!me] if entity <whatever item entity you want to check for> run effect give @s <potion effect> <duration in seconds>`.